# REACT Fetch request from mobile device doesn't works

Tags: android, reactjs, laravel-8, fetch-api

I'm building a pwa based on REACT that fetches the info from an API based on Laravel 8. In this pwa the first action that the user has to do is logging in.

On my PC it works perfectly, it makes the post request and returns the response to continue the process. But, when I try to do it on my Android, when I press the submit input, this doesn't do anything... No validation error, no success...

The function that does the fetch is this:

```
handleSubmit(event){
        let component = this;
        let headers = new Headers();

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        headers.append('Origin','http://192.168.1.132:3000');    

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', {
            mode: 'cors',
            method: 'post',
            headers: headers,
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        }).then(function(response) {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                component.setState({
                    error: 'Email and/or password are not correct'
                });
            }else{
                component.setState({
                    error: null
                });
                return response.json()
            }
        }).then(function(data) {
            component.props.onUserChange(data);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('Something went wrong...');
            console.log(component.state.error);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Do you know the cause of this? Is because the project is in local?

I'll appreciate any idea to solve this.

Comment: maybe because from device your api running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 is not accessible.

Comment: @Vivart that's it! Thanks! To solve it I used Ngrok ;)